# 500 Internal Server Error with RewriteRule, redirecting from old directory to new directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm sorry, I know there are a million mod_rewrite questions on here already. I looked through a good many and tried to learn from others' mistakes, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong here.

My site used to be at http://example.com/andrew/qa. Now it's at http://example.com/fdso.

I just want to redirect all `/andrew/qa/(.*)` URLs to `/fdso/$1`. Including changing the URL on the browser, which I understand the 301 option takes care of:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/andrew/qa/.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^/andrew/qa/(.*)$ /fdso/$1 [L,301]
</IfModule>
```

I have this in a .htaccess file at /andrew/qa/.htaccess.

I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error and can't figure out why.

And the server I'm on does not seem to generate logs for some reason. (The logs directory is missing.) I have very little control over this server, as I don't have root access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is causing 500 error:

```
RewriteRule ^/andrew/qa/(.*)$ /fdso/$1 [L,301]
```

It is because `301` should be `R=301`.

However your rule will still not redirect because of a leading `/` and presence of `/andrew/qa/` in `RewriteRule` pattern.

Have it this way in `/andrew/qa/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /fdso/$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

You also don't need redundant `RewriteCond`.

Comment: You are amazing. I've seen so many of your answers. Thank you!